Calculate$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$
Calculate
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
The following words are my answer:
$$=\exp\left(\lim{\sum{\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\right)^\frac{1}{n}}}\right)=\exp\left(\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right)}\right)$$
But I can not solve this improper integral. Is there any idea about solving integral like this?
What is more, how to do it without using the definition of integral?

with the substitution $u=\frac{\pi}2x$, you're left with the (famous) integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos u) \frac 2{\pi}du$

We have that
$$\log\left[\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right]=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\int_0^1 \log\left(\cos\left(\frac \pi 2 x\right)\right)dx$$
which, as noticed in the comments, by $u=\frac{\pi}2x$ reduces to the well-known integral
$$\boxed{L=\frac 2\pi \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \log\left(\cos u\right)du=\log \frac12}$$

As an alternative solution, we can avoid integrals using that by symmetry
$$C_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=S_n$$
and then
$$2\frac{C_n}n=\frac{C_n}n+\frac{S_n}n=\log\frac12+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(\sin\left(\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)$$
and assuming wlog $n=2m$
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(\sin\left(\pi\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\frac1{2m}\sum_{k=1}^{2m-1}\log\left(\sin\left(\frac \pi 2\frac{k}{m}\right)\right)=\frac1m\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\log\left(\sin\left(\frac \pi 2\frac{k}{m}\right)\right)=\frac{C_m}m$$
finally by $\frac{C_n}n \to L$ we have
$$2L=\log \frac12 + L \implies \boxed{L=\log \frac12}$$

@SineoftheTime Oh yes, at first I changed index but I think this is not really necessary. Thanks

+1. The second method is elegant.

@SineoftheTime Much appreciated! Thanks

@SineoftheTime Since $\log 2$ comes out summing the two identical series, I thought there was a way to reach the result in a simpler way!

Yes, this also follows from the fact that $\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\cos x)dx$

@SineoftheTime Yes and probably by integrals it is more simple to handle but my aim was avoid integrals.
